# Python Maximum Pairwise Product time limit exceeded error

Tags: python, algorithm

```
n = int(input())
a = [int(x) for x in input().split()]
product = 0
for i in range(n):
  for j in range(i + 1, n):
    product = max(product, a[i] * a[j])
print(product)
```

When I submit the above code to Corsera's coding judge system,

`Failed case #4/17: time limit exceeded (Time used: 9.98/5.00, memory used: 20918272/536870912.)`

has been returned.
How can I change it?

Comment: I guess the biggest one is the product of two greatest positive integers or two smallest negative ones. Thus you can only iterate the list once and store those 4 integers, which is O(n).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is in O(n^2). You can sort `a` and choose two larger value in `a` as a result in O(n log(n)) (if the input value for list `a` is positive).

```
input_list = sorted(a)
product = max(a[0]*a[1], a[-1] * a[-2]) #as suggested in comments if there is negative values
```

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be less time consuming to sort items in descending order at first, and then multiply first and second from sorted list (if all are positive of course)?